# Two Block Jump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was roaming around a forest in my single player survival world and kept taking fall damage.  One time right when I hit the ground I jumped and appeared to jump two blocks high (To the top of the tree).  I want to know if it just appeared that way, if it was a bug, or if the damage movement caused me to go that little bit farther to get to the top.  Thanks!

Comment: Damage knockback *can* make you jump higher, so you may have seen correctly. Here is one example: http://reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1ooytb/how_to_jump_two_blocks_high_in_minecraft_with_fire/. I do not know enough to give a full answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to jump any higher in a vanilla single player world.

From the [Minecraft Wiki page on Transportation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Transportation#Vertical_speeds):

> Using any method of elevating yourself that relies purely on jumping, including climbing a slope without stairs and pillar jumping, you cannot rise faster than about 2.0 m/s.

Sprinting allows you to jump further horizontally, but not vertically.
From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sprinting) page on sprinting:

> It is possible to jump across four blocks horizontally (although difficult), instead of the usual two blocks by sprinting, however the jump height is no higher than normal.

Comment: I am not sure this is true. Damage knockback *can* make you jump higher. Here is one example: http://reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1ooytb/how_to_jump_two_blocks_high_in_minecraft_with_fire/

Comment: @Kcats Damage knockback is not jumping.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you if you can manage to set yourself on fire or poison yourself, if you jump at the exact time you take damage, you can jump 2 blocks. I've done it many times before, but I think the best way to prove this is by jumping up a cactus. Try it yourself and see! I am also making a video about it, I'll add the link when done.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it’s possible to vertically make a 2 block jump. I was watching a video called last to stop running wins $1,000. The jump is somewhere around 5:15. He uses cactus blocks to make himself jump higher. Here’s the link:

Comment: Cool timing. +1

Answer (score 0):

Jump boost potions can increase your jump height/speed. Poison/fire effects can actually reset your fall height like any other form of damage. Any damage while midair will pop you up a VERY TINY AMOUNT and reset your fall counter. Let's say you jump from world height to bedrock and you get set on fire before jumping, you would fall for seemingly longer and the fire DOT would negate most if not all of your fall damage. So any damage if you get hit at the height of your jump would put you up slightly higher so you would be able to make a 2 block jump in the right circumstances.